# Writing Tables in Torch to file

Tags: lua, hdf5, torch

I am trying to save some tables of strings to files in Torch. I have tried using this Torch extension by Deepmind: [hdf5](https://github.com/deepmind/torch-hdf5).

```
require 'hdf5'
label = {'a', 'b','c','d'}

local myFile = hdf5.open(features_repo .. 't.h5', 'w')
myFile:write('label', label)
myFile:close()
```

I am getting the error:

```
/home/user/torch/install/bin/luajit: ...e/user/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/hdf5/group.lua:222: torch-hdf5: writing data of type string is not supported
```

Torch Tensors are written to file as intended.

I have also tried using [matio](https://github.com/soumith/matio-ffi.torch) to write to mat files (for MatLab). I am getting this error:

```
bad argument #1 to 'varCreate' (cannot convert 'number' to 'const char *')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because "label" is a table of strings, but the function `HDF5Group:_writeData` is expecting a form of "tensor".

Looking at `ffi.lua`, it seems that the "tensor" is a typedef for "integer", so maybe replace:

```
label = {'a', 'b','c','d'}
```

with 
   label = {1,2,3,4}

Comment: I need to save at able of strings unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function t2s from the module (https://github.com/aryajur/tableUtils.git) to generate a string you can save to a file. To convert back just use function s2t.